# read xlsx files in Rstudio

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I am taking the R programming class from Cousera, and while I was practising how to read in xlsx files using read.xlsx, I encountered the following error message:

```
dat<- read.xlsx(file="./data/nga.xlsx", sheetIndex=1)
```

> Error in `.jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,`  : 
>         java.util.zip.ZipException: oversubscribed literal/length tree

R version 3.2.1, R studio version 3.2.1, platform windows7 64bit. Can anyone give a hint what this message means and how to work around it?

Thanks,
Gezimao

Comment: Your RStudio version sounds wrong, for example mine is `Version 0.99.441`; you can get this by Help->About RStudio

Comment: About your issue, two things to try:
First run `gc()` and try again; second, try using `read.xlsx2` instead of `read.xlsx` and see what happens. If that doesn't work, make sure that the file path is correct, for example by using `list.files("./data/")` and make sure `nga.xlsx` is there.

Comment: From these ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183979/java-util-zip-zipexception-incomplete-literal-length-tree),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049448/java-util-zip-zipexception-oversubscribed-dynamic-bit-lengths-tree),[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377761/oversubscribed-literal-length-tree-error-while-creating-database)) questions about what the underlying `Java` is doing, it seems there's a problem with a `zip` file somehow, but I don't know why any `zip` files are getting involved.

Comment: If nothing works, you can try `readxl`, `openxlsx`, or any of these [Read Excel files from R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/read-excel-files-from-r/)

Comment: Why? `.xlsx` format is a zipped version of a variant XML. If you unzip one you get several folders that hold different components in .xml files

Comment: @BondedDust good to know, thanks. In that case, making sure you can actually open the file in Excel (or Libre/Open Office, etc.) without any errors is another step in debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The file you have downloaded was corrupted, so download again that file using the parameter 'mode="wb"'.

Answer (score 1):

try this package https://github.com/hadley/readxl

```
read_excel("my-new-spreadsheet.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The .xlsx file may be 'read only'.  Try 'Save As' to a new file from Excel and try read.xlsx again.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this java:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

then run your code and it should work. If it does check best answer :)